# div scrollbar with vertical "main" scrollbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I have a div with large content and a given height. The div has a scrollbar. What I want is to remove this scrollbar and let de div content be scrolled with the main scrollbar. When end of the div content is reached, the main scrollbar should scroll the rest of the page.

1. No scrollbar in "blue" div.
2. Get a Main scrollbar
3. Scrolling down will mean scroll and if div is reached, scroll div content, till end of content, after that scroll to footer.

I allready spent two nights on it and i'm really done with it now. Is this possible?

Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/og3r2169/

CSS

```
#container{
width: 80%;
margin: 0 auto;
}

#container-content {
background-color: grey;
width: 100%;
overflow: Hidden;
height: 600px
}

#content { 
background-color: blue;
max-height: 500px;
overflow: auto;
}

#footer {
background-color: red;
height: 200px;  
}
```

Comment: You just want to disable the div scrolling ? then remove the `max-height: 500px`

Comment: Not completely. I want to disable it but then the main verticle (browser) scrollbar needs to scroll the div. I know how I can disable the div scrolbar, its just there for my example

Comment: It is possible with a script, but by just remove the max height you will achieve the very same thing visually, so I can't understand why you would want to do like that? ... It will only put a very unnecessary workload on the browser which might cause a bad user experience.

Comment: @LGSon:  I want this because I have a background image and this one  is not allowed to grow/repeat etc. I want to place a div on it with main content of the site. The content is a lot more then the height of the background image. So I want to give the div a max-height, but i dont want to use the scrollbar of the div itself

Comment: But that you solve with `background-attachment: fixed`

Comment: GOing to give it a try tonight, need to go now. I'm happy with the help!

Comment: Also not working. Im going to change my design. It seems to be impossible

Comment: Nothing is impossible, the time to make it happen can differ though :), so if you post 2 images showing how it should look at load and when scrolled some, we likely will be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this:
js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

$('#container-content').scroll(function(){

var element = $('#content'),
        originalY = element.offset().top;
         var scrollTop = $('#container-content').scrollTop();
         if(scrollTop>=originalY){

         $('#content').animate({scrollTop:"+=50"});
         return false;
         }
});

});
```

css:

```
#container{
width: 80%;
margin: 0 auto;
overflow: hidden;
}

#container-content {
background-color: grey;
width: 100%;
overflow: scroll;
height: 400px
}

#content {
background-color: blue;
max-height: 500px;
overflow: hidden;
}

#footer {
background-color: red;
height: 200px;  
}
```

[fiddel](http://jsfiddle.net/RH8f6/663/)

Comment: Tried it but now the content div is scrolling automatically. This needs to be done by default browser scrollbar. The default browser scrollbar needs to scrol as usual but also the divs content.  When the end of the content is reached of the content div, the default scollbar needs to scroll the rest of the page

Answer (score 0):

Just change one thing:

```
#content {
  overflow: visible;
}
```

This will keep the `#container` in it's full length and let the surrounding element do the scrolling.

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/g23zox0y/

Comment: Checked it but now the content isn't scrollable anymore

Comment: So you want to scroll inside the div with the main scrollbar, and when the bottom of the div content is reached, continue to scoll the whole body with the main scrollbar? I don't think this is possible. Even if you'd find a JS method, you would have problems when it comes to responsiveness.

Comment: Exactly. Im going to change the design. Im done with this.